# receiving and sending multipart/form-data in mule 3.2

Tags: http, mule

I have problem in configuring Mule 3.2 which basically receive HTTP POST (multipart/form-data) and routing the payload and then send the payload by HTTP POST (multipart/form-data). How exactly to do that kind of task in Mule ?

Below are parts of my configuration

```
<flow name="UserBridgeFlow" doc:name="UserBridgeFlow">
    <inbound-endpoint address="http://${local.server}/${user.context}/" exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="STD_HTTP_CONNECTOR" doc:name="User Endpoint"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <transformer ref="RouteTransformer" doc:name="Transformer Reference"/>
    <response>
        <message-properties-transformer overwrite="true" doc:name="Message Properties">
            <add-message-property key="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
    </response>
    <response>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    </response>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://${user.server}/#[header:OUTBOUND:real.path]" doc:name="HTTP User"/>
    <default-exception-strategy>
        <processor-chain> 
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> 
        </processor-chain>
    </default-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

With above configuration, my binary data is always corrupted when reaching the other endpoint and also I get this error in the browser (caller endpoint) "*The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.*"

-- UPDATED CONFIGURATION --

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/mule.properties"/>
<custom-transformer class="id.co.zire.ebs.mule.transformer.RouteTransformer" name="RouteTransformer" doc:name="RouteTransformer"/>
<http:connector name="STD_HTTP_CONNECTOR" enableCookies="true" validateConnections="true" clientSoTimeout="20000" serverSoTimeout="10000" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
    <dispatcher-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="50" maxBufferSize="150"/>
    <reconnect count="3" frequency="2000"/>
</http:connector>
<flow name="HTTPBridgeFlow" doc:name="HTTPBridgeFlow">
    <composite-source>
        <inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://${local.server}/${user.context}/" encoding="ISO-8859-1" connector-ref="STD_HTTP_CONNECTOR" doc:name="User Endpoint"/>
        <inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://${local.server}/${cms.context}/" encoding="ISO-8859-1" connector-ref="STD_HTTP_CONNECTOR" doc:name="CMS Endpoint"/>
        <inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://${local.server}/${ads.context}/" encoding="ISO-8859-1" connector-ref="STD_HTTP_CONNECTOR" doc:name="Ads Endpoint"/>
    </composite-source>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <transformer ref="RouteTransformer" doc:name="Transform Header"/>
    <set-property propertyName="http.method" value="#[header:INBOUND:http.method]" doc:name="Copy HTTP method"/>
    <flow-ref name="HTTPResponseFlow" doc:name="HTTP Flow Reference"/>
</flow>
<sub-flow name="HTTPResponseFlow" doc:name="HTTPResponseFlow">
    <logger message="Payload Output : #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="message.inboundProperties['http.context.path'] contains '${user.context}'">
            <processor-chain>
                <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://${user.server}/#[message.inboundProperties['http.relative.path']]" responseTimeout="120000" doc:name="HTTP User"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <when expression="message.inboundProperties['http.context.path'] contains '${cms.context}'">
            <processor-chain>
                <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://${cms.server}/#[message.inboundProperties['http.relative.path']]" responseTimeout="120000" doc:name="HTTP CMS"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <when expression="message.inboundProperties['http.context.path'] contains '${ads.context}'">
            <processor-chain>
                <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://${ads.server}/#[message.inboundProperties['http.relative.path']]" responseTimeout="120000" doc:name="HTTP Ads"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
    </choice>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Set Cross-Domain Request Allowed">
        <add-message-property key="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add-message-property key="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS"/>
        <add-message-property key="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000"/>
        <add-message-property key="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
</sub-flow>
```

OK, now I have change most of the configuration, now I have problem of passing the included binary data in the HTTP POST message body. Mule seems to be altering the bytes before passing it to the outbound endpoint. I have create a custom transformer to get the payload manually and parse the binary data from the payload (payload type is String by the way) but the retrieved binary data from payload is already altered. For example below is part of the original file bytes in hexadecimal:

ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 (ÿØÿà..JF)

but Mule converts into:

3f 3f 3f 3f 00 10 4a 46 (????..JF)

I think it is encoding issue, maybe Mule converts it automatically to UTF-8

-- RouteTransformer.java --

```
public class RouteTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer{
    private static final String MULE_CONFIG = "/mule.properties";
    private static final String CLIENT_IP = "MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS";
    private static final String CLIENT_IP_HEADER = "Client-Ip";
    private static final String IP_REGEX = "/?((\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3}))(:(\\d{1,5}))?";
    private final String[] PASSING_HEADER;

    public RouteTransformer() throws IOException{
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(MULE_CONFIG));
        PASSING_HEADER = prop.getProperty("passing-header").split("\\s*,\\s*");
    }

    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException{
        // Copy 'passing' header
        for(int i=PASSING_HEADER.length; --i>=0; ){
            String headerName = PASSING_HEADER[i];
            Object val = message.getInboundProperty(headerName);
            if(headerName.equals(CLIENT_IP)){
                String s = (String) val;
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(IP_REGEX);
                Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
                if(!m.matches()) continue;
                else{
                    headerName = CLIENT_IP_HEADER;
                    val = m.group(1);
                }
            }
            if(val != null) message.setOutboundProperty(headerName, val);
        }

        // Routing message
        String requestString = message.getInboundProperty("http.request");
        String contextPath = message.getInboundProperty("http.context.path");
        if(requestString != null && contextPath != null)
            message.setOutboundProperty("http.real.path", requestString.substring(contextPath.length()));

        return message;
    }
}
```

-- Multipart/form-data example --

```
-----------------------------20037128598723
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Angga
-----------------------------20037128598723
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="adsImage"; filename="Penguins.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿà..JF -- and the rest of bytes --
```

I hope somebody can bring some solutions.
Thanks

Comment: Payload for incoming HTTP requests is InputStream, not String, which allows downstream processing to deal with encoding correctly. What is your transformer expecting? Can you share its code? Also: is the incoming HTTP request specifying a charset in Content-Type or not?

Comment: Hi David, I've updated my question with RouteTransformer.java code and also a piece of multipart/form-data body. If I make request with browser (Chrome or Firefox) There are no charset defined but If I make a request from Spring RestTemplate, for every text boundary, Charset is defined but not on the boundary that has bytes in it. And I'm pretty sure, before RouteTransformer is called, the payload is already String. Or do you have any other way to achieve my goal ? - Thanks -

Comment: I think the `echo-component` is the culprit: it must consume the stream and build the string. Remove it, it's a gadget anyway and is never to be used in a real production grade configuration.

Comment: Hi David, I just found out accidentally yesterday that Echo may have converted ContentLengthInputStream to String. Thanks anyway for pointing out the culprit. Now what's left to do is just parse the multipart/form-data and pass it as attachment to the outbound endpoint. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering if the issue you're facing is related to the lack of content type (or its default value) on the outbound HTTP interaction.

Try adding a message properties transformer (*or a copy properties message processor for 3.3.x users reading this*) to copy the "Content-Type" property from the inbound scope to the outbound one.

Also, for strictness' sake, configure this endpoint to use the POST method.

Comment: OK, after several days struggling, it's one of the problem of cross domain request. Now I've change my environment so that client (browser) only sends request (POST multipart/form-data) to the same origin. example of the message on the POST body is (-----------------------------20037128598723 Content-Disposition: form-data;\n name="name"\nAngga\n-----------------------------20037128598723\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="adsImage"; filename="Penguins.jpg"\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\nbytes).

Comment: I don't know why but Mule seems to be altering the bytes so that the resulting file (after uploaded) is almost 2 times of the original file. Do you know what am I missing here ? Is it implicit transformer on the HTTP Inbound Endpoint ? - Thanks

Comment: Have you done any of my suggested changes? If yes can you update your question with your latest configuration?

Comment: Hi David, yes i have copied the Content-Type to the outbound one, but now I'm facing different issue. I have updated my question with the new config, Thanks for your patient in helping me.

Answer (score 2):

In your content type you have to add `charset=utf-8`:

```
response.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8")

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```